# Tornado: difference between initialize() and prepare()

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, webserver, tornado

I am using *Tornado* as web server, and I've noticed [from the official guide](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html#overriding-requesthandler-methods) two functions, `initialize` and `prepare`, that are called before requests handling (*POST*, *GET* etc...).
But I cannot understand the difference between the twos: it seems they can be used for same things. Can you explain me if the functions have different use cases?

Comment: The manual describes it pretty well, no? `initialize` should just take arguments passed to the class, and basically nothing else. `Prepare` may do "actual work" related to the request.

Comment: If it was so clear then I wouldn't ask it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in doubt, use `prepare()`. `prepare()` is the appropriate place to do most things, because it can do anything that the regular handler methods can do (including calling `self.write()` or `self.render()`, or raising `tornado.web.HTTPError`).

Only use `initialize()` to process the arguments received from the `URLSpec` (nearly always by saving them to the instance variables). `initialize` may not call methods like `self.write`, and exceptions it raises may not be handled as cleanly, so keep it simple.

Comment: Is initialize called only once, at the start of server?

Comment: No. For every request, a new RequestHandler object will be created, and its initialize and prepare methods are both called.